# AngularJS rest call, followed by opening new window with body of response

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a table dynamically populated, the last column being the result of a function like this:

```
function actionsHtml(data) {
  $scope.link="/myRestTarget?restParam=" + data.value;
  return '<a target="_new" ng-href="{{link}}" ng-click="$event.preventDefault();linkClicked(link);">Explorer <i class="fa fa-binoculars"/></a>'
}
```

when the user clicks on a the column button, a rest call is initiated; which creates a doc; returns the id of this doc; appends the id to the uri and then opens it in a new window.

```
$scope.linkClicked = function(link){
  $http.get(link.toString()).then(function (result) {
    var newLink = 'http://newUrl:8080/' + result.data.body
    $window.open(newLink, '_blank')
  });
};
```

The rest + window open works exactly as intended. However the $scope.link value is always the same (and always the column of the last row in the table). Now I get why this is the case - link is set by each row in turn. However I am unable to bind a value to the cell in question - unless I use $scope.link the value of $scope.linkClicked is always undefined....

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer - kind of obvious really :S

```
function actionsHtml(data) {
  var link="/myRestTarget?restParam=" + data.value;
  return '<a target="_new" href="' + link + '" ng-click="$event.preventDefault();linkClicked(link);">Explorer <i class="fa fa-binoculars"/></a>'
}
```